# Why my piece of my code is returning string array of size 0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am doing an automation using java selenium. I have written a code which gets all the text from the drop-down in a web page and stores it in a string array. If I print that string array, I can see all the text values, but when I return that and assign to other string array and print, it displays with empty array.

Below is my code.

```
public static String[] selectFromDropDown() {
    String[] available_text_1 = new String[list_of_text_available.size()];
    //list_of_text_available is a list of WebElement.
    for (int i = 0; i < list_of_text_available.size(); i++) {
        available_text_1[i] = list_of_text_available.get(i).getText();
    }
    return available_text_1;
// When I print available_text_1, then I can see all the text values.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] available_text_2 = selectFromDropDown();
// But when I print available_text_2 here, I am getting empty String array
}
```

Can somebody help me and tell what is the mistake in my code.

Comment: Posted code is not legal. `selectFromDropDown()` is an instance method.

Comment: Your code should not work. Give the code, that worked.

Comment: When you invoke the `new String[ ]` you pass the size parameter of `list_of_text_available.size()` can you confirm that this method is returning an int greater than 0? Maybe underneath your `String [ ] ` invocation do a `System.out.println(list_of_text_available.size());` just to confirm you're not creating an array of size 0

Comment: Also when you are populating the Array you do not need `list_of_text_available.get(i).getText()` instead `list_of_text_available.get(i)` will return the element at the specified index.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please help me out how can I fix this.

Comment: @Mukit09 I m not getting any error. When I do System.out.println(available_text_2), i can see the output as [ ] and nothing else. I don't have any working code.

Comment: @Bradley list_of_text_available.size() is giving an int greater than 0 and not creating an array size of 0. Even if I created an array with size 0, then I would have got an error in the for loop itself. 

list_of_text_available.get(i) this will return a webelement and not the text which I need actually to store in available_text_1 string array

Comment: of course, it should have error. You are calling a non static method from a static method without any instance. You even can't compile it. @CaptainMeow

Comment: @Mukit09  I edited my code and made selectFromDropDown() static

Comment: Try doing some de-bugging inside selectFromDropDown, try and show us the result of your de-bug here.

Comment: I got the issue. I thank Mukit09 and Bradley. I was using the list list_of_text_available.size() even before the element was visible and hence the size was zero. Solved it by putting it in right place